# Unable to install MCP2221 Driver on Win10 64bit OS

Tags: usb, embedded, serial, microchip, serial-bus

I use this PIC32MZEF board - https://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails/dm320007. It needs MCP2221 driver tobe installed for UART communication with PC.

I downloaded from official website.
[image]
But it throws following error.

> "The current language is not supported by the Device Driver Installation Wizard. Contact the vendor that provided you this package."

[image]

I asked microchip support team and got to know that MCP2221 Driver is pre-installed with Win10 OS. But when I connect USB, No virtual Com Port created.

[image]

Very similar issue was faced by @Doug12745 in this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329567/mcp2221a-usb-to-usart-with-windows-10-drivers). He was at-least able to install the driver back then. There is no proper answer for this question yet. So please reply if anyone know solution.

Comment: Why don't you force-install the driver?

Comment: @VoltageSpike : 
There is an update : I am actually now able to install the driver successfully. Microchip support team suggested a simple change that the language setting of apps must be changed to English(US) instead of English(India). Win10 has separate language settings for keyboard, apps, display and speech. I didnot know that. However the problem of no virtual Com port creation still persists even after installation of driver. (I tried restarting system, plugging off and on etc). I still need help with that.

Comment: update : June 1st Tuesday night I got a windows update notification and it ran overnight. Next day it detected my  PIC32MZ UART Com Port. I have absolutely no idea how it started working as the update mentioned something about bluetooth driver. I wish I knew about USB Device Tree software earlier so that I could have seen what exactly was the problem.

So anyone else when face the same problem please take log from USB Device Tree software for your USB Port and paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the same error message and I solved it in 3 steps:

1. Changed my language from English UK to English United States
2. Restarted my PC
3. Installed the driver package again